# I want to write an algorithm in overleaf, but it comes up with errors

Tags: algorithms

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{program}
\savesymbol{AND}
\savesymbol{OR}
\savesymbol{NOT}
\savesymbol{TO}
\savesymbol{COMMENT}
\savesymbol{BODY}
\savesymbol{IF}
\savesymbol{ELSE}
\savesymbol{ELSIF}
\savesymbol{FOR}
\savesymbol{WHILE}


\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Initialization} \label{algorithm: cds bw}
\textbf{Input:}
    V, E, S, S\textsubscript{ai}, P, P\textsubscript{ai}, R\textsubscript{s}, p\textsubscript{a},r\textsubscript{asp}, 
    $a \in V$, ${s\textsubscript{i} \in s\textsubscript{ai}}$ , $r \in  R$\\
    \hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \textbf{Output:} 
    W\textsubscript{r} ($r \in R$), P\textsubscript{va} ($a \in V$)
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State $UA \gets V$ 
        \State $T \gets 0$
        \State $Makspan \gets 0$
        \State $SrtS \gets Sort(S)$
        \State $rXs \gets SrtS$
        \For{$s \in S$}
        \State $Wr \gets Compute$
        \EndFor   
        \For{ $a \in V$}
        \State $P\textsubscript{va} \gets Compute$
        \EndFor          
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Your code is not compileable !

Comment: @AndréC i have forgot the \end {document}

Comment: First a document class, then loading packages, then begin the document and now you can start the algorithm.

Comment: @IftikharAhmad You can modify your question by clicking on the `edit` button

Comment: I am still unable to run this. All the things are working but only the line numbers are not displaying correctly.

Comment: There are many mistakes in your code, as pointed out by AndréC and Johannes_B. You'll see that overleaf also shows you the error messages. Unless you solve these, there is no way the result will look as intended.

Comment: I am a bit confused. This isthe code from here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456586/i-want-to-write-an-algorithm-but-things-went-wrong, you just changed things, which are obviously responsible for the errors. Why don't you just go back to the answer Werner posted back then?

Answer (score 1):

As we wrote in the comments, your document has many issues. You should probably familiarize yourself with the common structure for LaTeX documents. As Johannes_B wrote: "First a document class, then loading packages, then begin the document and now you can start the algorithm." More details [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure).

Your particular example is easy to fix once you stick to these rules.

```
%this comes first
\documentclass{article}

%then this
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%I dont know what all this is for
%\usepackage{program}
%\usepackage{savesym}
%\savesymbol{AND}
%\savesymbol{OR}
%\savesymbol{NOT}
%\savesymbol{TO}
%\savesymbol{COMMENT}
%\savesymbol{BODY}
%\savesymbol{IF}
%\savesymbol{ELSE}
%\savesymbol{ELSIF}
%\savesymbol{FOR}
%\savesymbol{WHILE}

%everything you \begin, you also have to \end
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
            \caption{Initialization} \label{algorithm: cds bw}
            \textbf{Input:}
            V, E, S, S\textsubscript{ai}, P, P\textsubscript{ai}, R\textsubscript{s}, p\textsubscript{a},r\textsubscript{asp}, 
            $a \in V$, ${s\textsubscript{i} \in s\textsubscript{ai}}$ , $r \in  R$\\
            \hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \textbf{Output:} 
            W\textsubscript{r} ($r \in R$), P\textsubscript{va} ($a \in V$)
            \begin{algorithmic}
                    \State $UA \gets V$ 
                    \State $T \gets 0$
                    \State $Makspan \gets 0$
                    \State $SrtS \gets Sort(S)$
                    \State $rXs \gets SrtS$
                    \For{$s \in S$}
                    \State $Wr \gets Compute$
                    \EndFor   
                    \For{ $a \in V$}
                    \State $P\textsubscript{va} \gets Compute$
                    \EndFor          
            \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited your answer: TeX to LaTeX. If you are answering about overall TeXs, i.e. TeX, LaTeX and ConTeXt, be free to roll back!